# passport local vs custom authntication

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

how passport local strategy vs custom code

```
// passport involved code

app.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local'),
  function(req, res) {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
    res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
  });
```

I can also call my local function which can check the same thing which passport local strategy checks so therefore why to create local strategy

```
// custom checking function

app.post('/login',
  customfunctionhere,
  function(req, res) {
    // If this function gets called, authentication was successful.
    // `req.user` contains the authenticated user.
    res.redirect('/users/' + req.user.username);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write your own local strategy function. However, passport gives you extras like persisting the login (cookies), easily handing success and failure, and more.

Plus, if you are using other strategies like OAuth or google/fb/twitter single sign-on, then using passport for all authentication makes sense.

Note: you do not pass a validation function to `passport.authenticate()`. Check the `passport-local` docs for more info: https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local